# Metal Compute pipeline not working on MacOS, but working on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, gpgpu, metal

I'm trying to do some GPGPU computations with Metal. I have a basic Metal pipeline that:

- creates the required `MTLComputePipelineState` pipeline and all the associated objects (`MTLComputeCommandEncoder`, command queue and so on);
- creates a target texture for writing (using `desc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;`);
- launches a basic shader to fill this texture with some values (in my experiments, either setting one of the color component to 1 or creating a grey-valued gradient based on the thread coordinates);
- reads back the content of this texture from the GPU.

I'm testing this code in 2 setups:

- on OSX 10.11 with a MacBook Pro early 2013;
- on iOS 9 with an iPhone 6.

The **iOS version runs just fine** and I get exactly what I ask the shader to do. On **OSX however** I get a valid (non-nil, with correct size) output texture. However, when fetching the data back **all I get is 0 everywhere**.

Am I missing a step that would be specific to the OS X implementation? This seems to happen with **both the NVIDIA GT650M** and the **Intel HD4000**, or possibly a bug in the runtime?

As I have currently no idea on how to investigate further the issue, any help in this regard would also be greatly appreciated :-)

**EDIT - My current implementation**

This is the initial (failing) state of my implementation. It's a bit long but mostly boilerplate code to create the pipeline:

```
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
id<MTLLibrary> library = [device newDefaultLibrary];
id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];

NSError *error = nil;
id<MTLComputePipelineState> pipeline = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:[library
                                                                                    newFunctionWithName:@"dummy"]
                                                                             error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
MTLTextureDescriptor *desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm
                                                                                width:16
                                                                               height:1
                                                                            mipmapped:NO];
desc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;

id<MTLTexture> texture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:desc];

MTLSize threadGroupCounts = MTLSizeMake(8, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake([texture width]  / threadGroupCounts.width,
                                   [texture height] / threadGroupCounts.height,
                                   1);

id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];

id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> commandEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[commandEncoder setComputePipelineState:pipeline];

[commandEncoder setTexture:texture atIndex:0];
[commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCounts];
[commandEncoder endEncoding];

[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
```

The code used to get the data is the following (I've split the file in two parts to get smaller code chunks):

```
// Get the data back
uint8_t* imageBytes = malloc([texture width] * [texture height] * 4);
assert(imageBytes);
MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, [texture width], [texture height]);
[texture getBytes:imageBytes bytesPerRow:[texture width]*4 fromRegion:region mipmapLevel:0];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    NSLog(@"Pix = %d %d %d %d",
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i),
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i + 1),
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i + 2),
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i + 3));
}
```

And this is the shader code (writing 1 to red and alpha, should become 0xff in the output buffer when read on the host):

```
#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

kernel void dummy(texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                  uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    outTexture.write(float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), gid);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Synchronization code:

```
[commandEncoder setTexture:texture atIndex:0];
[commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCounts];
[commandEncoder endEncoding];

//
// synchronize texture from gpu to host mem
//
id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];
[blitEncoder synchronizeTexture:texture slice:0 level:0];
[blitEncoder endEncoding];

[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
```

This is tested on Mac Book mid 2012 with the same GPUs that you have and mid 2015 with AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 МБ.

Some time i use the follow trick to get texture data without synchronization:

```
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> commandEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[commandEncoder setComputePipelineState:pipeline];

[commandEncoder setTexture:texture atIndex:0];
[commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCounts];
[commandEncoder endEncoding];

//
// one trick: copy texture from GPU mem to shared
//
id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];

[blitEncoder copyFromTexture:texture
                 sourceSlice: 0
                 sourceLevel: 0
                sourceOrigin: MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0)
                  sourceSize: MTLSizeMake([texture width], [texture height], 1)
                    toBuffer: texturebuffer
           destinationOffset: 0
      destinationBytesPerRow: [texture width] * 4
    destinationBytesPerImage: 0];

[blitEncoder endEncoding];

[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];


// Get the data back
uint8_t* imageBytes = [texturebuffer contents];

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    NSLog(@"Pix = %d %d %d %d",
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i),
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i + 1),
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i + 2),
          *((uint8_t*)imageBytes + 4 * i + 3));
}
```

Both approaches work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll test tonight at home and will let you know the outcome. As it seems unnatural to add this sync code (it's not even mentioned in the programming guide), I may fill a radar later on.

Comment: Oh very cool, it did work! Thanks for your help. I'll report this as a bug to Apple (at least, hopefully they will update the developer guides).

Comment: Out of curiosity: did the original code (without the blit call) work on the Mac with the AMD card? I'd like to check if it's a driver-related issue or something more general to the Mac OS Metal implementation.

Comment: No, it didn't work. i suppose it's the OSX Metal implementation.

Comment: Works great on macOS 11 with AMD. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you didn't call  [- synchronizeTexture:slice:level:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLBlitCommandEncoder_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLBlitCommandEncoder/synchronizeTexture:slice:level:)
May be the follow example (part of jpeg-turbo writer class implementation) can solve your issue:

```
    row_stride = (int)cinfo.image_width  * cinfo.input_components; /* JSAMPLEs per row in image_buffer */

uint   counts        = cinfo.image_width * 4;
uint   componentSize = sizeof(uint8);
uint8 *tmp = NULL;
if (texture.pixelFormat == MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm) {
    tmp  = malloc(row_stride);
    row_stride *= 2;
    componentSize = sizeof(uint16);
}

//
// Synchronize texture with host memory 
//
id<MTLCommandQueue> queue             = [texture.device newCommandQueue];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer    = [queue commandBuffer];
id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];

[blitEncoder synchronizeTexture:texture slice:0 level:0];
[blitEncoder endEncoding];

[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];

void       *image_buffer  = malloc(row_stride);

int j=0;
while (cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {

    MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, cinfo.next_scanline, cinfo.image_width, 1);

    [texture getBytes:image_buffer
                   bytesPerRow:cinfo.image_width * 4 * componentSize
                    fromRegion:region
                   mipmapLevel:0];

    if (texture.pixelFormat == MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm) {
        uint16 *s = image_buffer;
        for (int i=0; i<counts; i++) {
            tmp[i] = (s[i]>>8) & 0xff;
            j++;
        }
        row_pointer[0] = tmp;
    }
    else{
        row_pointer[0] = image_buffer;
    }
    (void) jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
}

free(image_buffer);
if (tmp != NULL) free(tmp);
```

It was tested on mid 2012 mac book pro with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 МБ.

[Discussion on Apple developer forums.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30488)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work in my case. I'm using a `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`instead of a bit command encoder, and the `-synchronizeTexture:` message isn't available. It is replaced by `-dispatchThreadgroups:` which I do call.

Comment: You can use blit encoder independently and simultaneously with any others MTL encoders. Blit encoder just accelerates some useful operations like data copping and memory synchronization. In example above i've just shown one of the approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is example when we can use a blit command encoder and a compute command encoder simultaneously. After any computations you can apply blit operations, or in any context what you want.

```
        self.context.execute { (commandBuffer) -> Void in
        //
        // clear buffer
        //
        let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.blitCommandEncoder()
        blitEncoder.fillBuffer(buffer, range: NSMakeRange(0, buffer.length), value: 0)

        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()

        //
        // create compute pipe
        //
        commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(self.kernel.pipeline!);
        commandEncoder.setTexture(texture, atIndex:0)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer, offset:0, atIndex:0)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(self.channelsToComputeBuffer,offset:0, atIndex:1)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(self.regionUniformBuffer,    offset:0, atIndex:2)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(self.scaleUniformBuffer,     offset:0, atIndex:3)

        self.configure(self.kernel, command: commandEncoder)

        //
        // compute 
        //
        commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(self.threadgroups, threadsPerThreadgroup:threadgroupCounts);
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()

        //
        // synchronize texture state
        // 
        [blitEncoder synchronizeTexture:texture slice:0 level:0];
        [blitEncoder endEncoding];

    }
```

Comment: I tried adding a blit encoder to force the synchronization, but it didn't help (I still get the same empty result).

Comment: Can you share your example code? I'll try to test one on gpu chip sets that i have in my apple devices.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I really appreciate. I've added the code for both the pipeline side and the shader.

Comment: Don't mind:) I've been developing for two months image processing framework based on Metal and interested in collecting issues that can occur on different platforms. I've just tested your example with some additional lines of code, you may see theirs below in the next answer.